# End Editing on NSTableView (View Based)

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

When a user is mid-editing a textfield on a tableview and decides to click the close button for the window, the changes he/she made does not get saved. How can I force a tableview (view based) to end editing (not abort editing) ?

Comment: I couldn't make the answer work for me when I was using storyboards and segues to modal sheets in my project. I ended up having my `viewController` as a delegate of the `NSTextField`'s within the table cell view. Then I toggled the `isEnabled` flag of the sheet's 'OK' button as the cell view's text field fired `control(_ control: NSControl, textShouldBeginEditing fieldEditor: NSText) -> Bool` and `control(_ control: NSControl, textShouldEndEditing fieldEditor: NSText) -> Bool`. It's not pretty, but it forces the user to end editing the cell's text and then confirm their entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to assign a delegate for your window and respond to `NSWindow`'s [-windowShouldClose:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008202-CH1-SW37) delegate method. In it, invoke [-makeFirstResponder:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/makeFirstResponder%3a) to make the window itself the first responder, noting the `BOOL` answer it gives. You should return whatever `-makeFirstResponder:` answers as the answer to the delegate `...ShouldClose:` message since it may not be able to end editing / resign first responder. Assuming it's successful, it'll end editing and trigger whatever action / bindings machinery you set up prior to actually closing. This works because `NSTableView` and the views it uses in view-based mode are subclasses of `NSControl` and automatically handles the responder status changes by ending editing, etc. Hope this helps.